# Show that $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}, (3+\sqrt 7)^n+(3-\sqrt 7)^n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and that $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}, (2+\sqrt 2)^n+(2-\sqrt 2)^n\in\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got this problem which I encountered during a limit of sequence calculation:

Show that $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}, (3+\sqrt 7)^n+(3-\sqrt 7)^n\in\Bbb{Z}$
And that
$\forall n\in\Bbb{N}, (2+\sqrt 2)^n+(2-\sqrt 2)^n\in\Bbb{Z}$

I tried induction but I failed to show it.
Thanks on any help.

Note: I don't know advanced number theory.

Comment: Do you know about binomial expansion?

Comment: The sequence is therefore twice Sloane's A146963.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Way 1:  *Imagine expanding* using the Binomial Theorem, and adding. There is nice cancellation of the terms that involve odd powers of $\sqrt{7}$.

Way 2:  Our sum is invariant under the mapping that sends numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{7}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, to $a-b\sqrt{7}$. But it is not hard to see that only integers are invariant under that mapping.

Way 3:  We can also use a recurrence.
Note that $3+\sqrt{7}$ and $3-\sqrt{7}$ are roots of the equation $x^2-6x+2=0$. Let $a_n=(3+\sqrt{7})^n$ and $b_n=(3-\sqrt{7})^n$. It is easy to verify that $a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-2a_n$ and $b_{n+2}=6b_{n+1}-2b_n$.

Let $c_n=(3+\sqrt{7})^n+(3-\sqrt{7})^n$. Then by linearity we have
$$c_{n+2}=6c_{n+1}-2c_n.\tag{1}$$
Note that $c_0=2$ and $c_1=6$, both integers. It follows by induction using (1) that $c_n$ is an integer for all $n$.

Way 4: For brevity write our sum as $\alpha^n +\beta^n$. Note that
$$\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha^n +\beta^n)(\alpha +\beta)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1}).\tag{1}$$ 
Since $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are integers, using (1) we can show that
if $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and $\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1}$ are integers, then so is
$\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}$. This does the induction step.

Comment: I really like Way 2! No computation is needed.

Answer (score 7):

If you know a bit of abstract algebra, there is nothing to compute. (And this is one of those examples which show that abstraction doesn't make things complicated, but in fact easier.)

Consider the [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Its automorphism group is generated by $\sqrt{7} \mapsto -\sqrt{7}$. Since $(3+\sqrt{7})^n + (3-\sqrt{7})^n \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ is obviously invariant under this transformation, it lies in $\mathbb{Q}$. It is also integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ (since $3,\sqrt{7}$ are integral). Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed, the element actually lies in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The same argument works for $(2+\sqrt{2})^n+(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ and tons of other examples. For example, $(1+i)^n + (1-i)^n \in \mathbb{Z}$ by considering the field of Gaussian rationals $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

*Edit*: As explained by André Nicolas  in  this answer, the argument gets even simpler by working directly with the *ring* $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$.

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$\begin{align}(3+\sqrt 7)^n+(3-\sqrt 7)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}(\sqrt 7)^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}(-\sqrt 7)^k\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}(\sqrt 7)^k(1+(-1)^k).\end{align}$$Here, note that if $k$ is odd, then 
$$(\sqrt 7)^k(1+(-1)^k)=0$$
and that if $k$ is even, then $$(\sqrt 7)^k(1+(-1)^k)\in\mathbb Z.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $b$ are *any* integers (positive or negative), then $(a+\sqrt b)^n + (a-\sqrt b)^n$ is an integer. This is because if you expand it out using the binomial expansion, the terms $(\sqrt b)^m$ from $(a+\sqrt b)^n$ cancel out the terms $(-\sqrt b)^m$ from $(a-\sqrt b)^n$ for odd $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In the binomial expansion of

$$(3+\sqrt 7)^n+(3-\sqrt 7)^n$$

we have terms such as

$$3^n+3^{n-1}\sqrt 7{n\choose 1}+3^{n-2}\sqrt 7^2{n\choose 2}+\dots$$

What happens when two such binomials are expanded, particularly when one of them involves a negative?

Alternative hint:

What happens in the following multiplication:

$$((2+\sqrt2)^n+(2-\sqrt2)^n)((2+\sqrt2)+(2-\sqrt2))$$

(This one may lend itself to induction...)

Answer (score 1):

It's a great idea to look at $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$.

But if you haven't gotten to algebraic number theory in your studies just yet, let's try basic algebra. I shall use $n$ here to refer to 0 or a positive integer.

What's the formula for $(3 - \sqrt{7})^n$? Define the recurrence relations $a_n = 6a_{n - 1} - 2a_{n - 2}$, with $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3$ and $b_n = 6b_{n - 1} - 2b_{n - 2}$ with $b_1 = 1, b_2 = 6$. Then, $(3 - \sqrt{7})^n = a_n - b_n \sqrt{7}$ for $n > 0$. Verify this before going further. Verify also that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers.

Now, what's the formula for $(3 + \sqrt{7})^n$? It turns out to be very similar, and it even employs the same recurrence relations defined earlier. Thus, $(3 + \sqrt{7})^n = a_n + b_n \sqrt{7}$.

Putting it all together: $(3 - \sqrt{7})^n + (3 + \sqrt{7})^n = a_n - b_n \sqrt{7} + a_n + b_n \sqrt{7} = 2a_n$.